# Python files are not displayed while running through another python code

Tags: python, file, raspberry-pi

I have two python file `file1` and `file2` and I want to run these two files simultaneously on RASPBERRY Pi (with Raspian) using another python, and I wrote following python code:

**Python code:**

```
import subprocess

print 'Process Start'
subprocess.Popen(["python", '/home/pi/Desktop/file1.py'])
print 'Process 1 completed'
subprocess.Popen(["python", '/home/pi/Desktop/file2.py'])
print 'Process 2 completed'
```

**Output:**

```
Process Start
Process 1 completed
Process 2 completed
```

However I think the `file1` and `file2` don't get executed as both files ask for input from user. How can I fix this problem?

I am new to python and Raspberry pi ,please explain the solution in little bit detail.

Comment: check this link : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=97851

Comment: the first comment on above mentioned link is not working. If  you know any possible method ,please mention here

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html:

> The recommended way to launch subprocesses is to use the following
>   convenience functions. For more advanced use cases when these do not
>   meet your needs, use the underlying Popen interface.
>
> `subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`
>   Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

Use this.

`Popen` is more flexible, but that also means you'll have to take care of all the right parameters, and you'll have to `wait()` for the process to finish.

Comment: after using the subprocess.call() , i am getting the same output as i mentioned with no file console open to provide input for file1 & file 2. Can you please help me over this issue.

Comment: are you running from a graphical interface? the subprocesses will inherit the console of their parent.

Comment: i am running the code on raspberry pi using python 2.7 and excepting execution of above mentioned python files on two different consoles..both the files just deal with GPIO pins only.